# Using openpxl and python to import a xlsx file

Tags: python, arrays, plot, openpyxl

I have a multiple sheet excel workbook and I want to import two columns from on of the sheets in the workbook how do I do that? I have been looking everywhere online and it is no where. I am trying to use the package openpyxl.

Comment: You really should provide a sample of your current code and ask specific a question about a specific part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this:

```
from openpyxl import *

#import the excel workbook
wb = load_workbook('input.xlsx')
#this should give you the sheet names
WSheets = wb.sheetnames

#iterate through sheets
for i in WSheets:
    ws = wb[i]
    #To access values from a particular column of the sheet, for example column B
    print ws['B']
```

Should give

```
(<Cell vane.B1>, <Cell vane.B2>, <Cell vane.B3>, <Cell vane.B4>, <Cell vane.B5>, <Cell vane.B6>, <Cell vane.B7>, <Cell vane.B8>, <Cell vane.B9>, <Cell vane.B10>, <Cell vane.B11>, <Cell vane.B12>, <Cell vane.B13>, <Cell vane.B14>, <Cell vane.B15>, <Cell vane.B16>, <Cell vane.B17>, <Cell vane.B18>, <Cell vane.B19>, <Cell vane.B20>, <Cell vane.B21>, <Cell vane.B22>, <Cell vane.B23>, <Cell vane.B24>, <Cell vane.B25>, <Cell vane.B26>, <Cell vane.B27>, <Cell vane.B28>, <Cell vane.B29>)
```

and so on...

Note: I am using `openpyxl 2.4.0-a1` earlier versions may have different syntax.